# How to process an Array with object properties to generate react elements

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and came from a jQuery background. I wanted to process an array of DOM elements that could be existed dynamically/randomly in the document. The properties define the Dom element type, attributes, and location via its parent.

I managed to achieve this with JQuery looping through the array and injecting HTML elements under its respectful parent using .appendTo() without defining a nested function using react.CreateElement to deal with each array item on a case per case bases.

```js
//Array Example
 
       var data = [
                {
                    "component": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                    "id": "grid00",
                    "className": "grid"
                    },
                    "parent": "header"
                },
                {
                    "component": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                    "id": "row00",
                    "className": "row"
                    },
                    "parent": "grid00"
                },
                {
                    "component": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                    "id": "pivot00",
                    "className": "ms-Pivot ms-Pivot--large ms-Pivot--tabs tab-content"
                    },
                    "parent": "row00"
                },
                {
                    "component": "ul",
                    "attributes": {
                    "id": "pivotLinks00",
                    "className": "ms-Pivot-links nav-pills"
                    },
                    "parent": "pivot00"
                }
            ]

//JQuery Code Sample: 

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length;i++){
                $(`<${data[i].component} id="${data[i].attributes.id}" class="${data[i].attributes.className}">This is ${data[i].attributes.id} </${data[i].component}>`).appendTo(`#${data[i].parent}`);
                
                }
```

```css
div{
border-style: solid;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header"></div>
```

I was trying to put something together in react like the below but not getting my head around it to create the elements in a nested manner similar to JQuery even though I am passing the parent element Id, they are created on the same level (HTML end results in the screenshot):

```js
 var data = [
                {
                    "component": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                    "id": "grid00",
                    "className": "grid"
                    },
                    "parent": "header"
                },
                {
                    "component": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                    "id": "row00",
                    "className": "row"
                    },
                    "parent": "grid00"
                },
                {
                    "component": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                    "id": "pivot00",
                    "className": "ms-Pivot ms-Pivot--large ms-Pivot--tabs tab-content"
                    },
                    "parent": "row00"
                },
                {
                    "component": "ul",
                    "attributes": {
                    "id": "pivotLinks00",
                    "className": "ms-Pivot-links nav-pills"
                    },
                    "parent": "pivot00"
                }
            ]
                     
const ProcessObject = (props) => {  
  return props.data.map((data, index) => <Node key={index} {...data}/>)
}
                        
function Node(props){
  return (
      React.createElement(`${props.component}`,{id: props.attributes.id},`this is ${props.attributes.id}`, document.getElementById(props.parent))
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <div className="header">Header</div>
        <ProcessObject data={data}/>
     </div>
    );
  } 
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>, document.getElementById('mountNode')
);
```

```css
div{
border-style: solid;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="mountNode"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the updated question:
React is unidirectional in nature and that is `parent -> child`.
According to data structure, you are defining elements based on a `children -> parent`
relationship, which wont work as far as i know using react.

For the sake of explaining to you i have created a very basic solution with an updated data structure which allows a `parent -> child` relationship.

```
const newData = [
{
component: "div",
attributes: {
  id: "grid00",
  className: "grid"
},
children: {
  component: "div",
  attributes: {
    id: "row00",
    className: "row"
  },
  children: {
    component: "div",
    attributes: {
      id: "pivot00",
      className: "ms-Pivot ms-Pivot--large ms-Pivot--tabs tab-content"
    },
    children: {
      component: "ul",
      attributes: {
        id: "pivotLinks00",
        className: "ms-Pivot-links nav-pills"
      },
      parent: "pivot00"
    }
  }
}
}
];
```

This way the nodes and children elements can be recursively created to form the element tree.
Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-cherry-rvbrk) for the whole code working as you expected.

Hope this makes sense in what you are finally trying to achieve.

Comment: The explanation made sense and thanks for trying to help me out with the parent -> child relationship example. It did work on the current data-structure that you have updated, so I went ahead and added <li> elements under <ul > element but unfortunately, I couldn't add more than on the same level. One more note that I could have multiple rows on the same level that has children of other <div> and <li>.

Comment: I have included the multiple <li> example below:

children: {
  component: "ul",
  attributes: {
    id: "pivotLinks00",
    className: "ms-Pivot-links nav-pills"
  },
  parent: "pivot00",
  children: {
    component: "li",
    attributes: {
      id: "Links00",
      className: "ms-Pivot-links nav-pills"
    },
    parent: "pivot00",
  },
  children: {
    component: "li",
    attributes: {
      id: "Links01",
      className: "ms-Pivot-links nav-pills"
    },
    parent: "pivot00",
  },
}

Comment: you can also handle multiple children similarly by creating an array of all sibling children elements recursively. i have updated the code for multiple sibling children here : 
 https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-sky-qjp0m

Comment: In the initial testing, I could say this is working for me, I will mark this as an answer. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have the react concepts correct other than in the functional component `ProcessObject`, nothing is returned.

You can easity solve this by:
**Solution 1**:

```
const ProcessObject = (props) => {  
  return props.data.map(data => <Node {...data}/>)
}
```

**Solution 2**:

```
const ProcessObject = (props) => props.data.map(data => <Node {...data}/>)
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, this has helped me to compile my code, I have updated my question and added more clear details with working react code.

Comment: ok. i have added a new answer since now the question is very different after your update.

Answer (score 0):

Edit based on updated question:

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hLmtq0g9/
React components can be used the same way you would use recursive functions.

```
const data = [
    {
        //some keys
        children: //structure of data repeats
    }
];

class Example extends React.Component {
    render(){
        <div>
            <!-- use data keys -->
            <Example data={data.children} />
        </div>
    }
}

<Example data={data} />
```

Older Answer:
You need to use the `map` in render function.

```
const items = [
        { text: "Learn JavaScript", id: '1' },
        { text: "Learn React", id: '2' },
        { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", id: '3' },
        { text: "Build something awesome", id: '4' }
      ];

class Example extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Todos:</h2>
        <ol>
        {items.map(item => (
          <li id={item.id}>{item.text}</li>
        ))}
        </ol>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Play around with it here https://jsfiddle.net/utfxcnko/

Comment: I have updated my question, I am trying to create a nested structure instead of rendering all the elements on the same level. thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to react you should check out this [lesson](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-use-map-to-create-react-components-from-arrays-of-data). That will indeed help you to get a clear view of how to create components form an array of data.

Comment: Thanks, defiantly could use it, but I am aware of how to render the elements in typical scenario as of all array items on under the same parent/level. But I needed help on how to render as a nested element under different parent/level. My question updated with working code and screenshot of end result